# Add a review audit with a URL removed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits

**I propose adding a new review audit:** *claiming that a URL is dead and removing it from the post.*

Okay, so this particular answer might not be great anyway, due to being made up of just links, but the URL is still alive, and 2 users have blindly accepted [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1874215).

This isn't the first time I've seen it either:

[image: a]

Comment: Do we have evidence that this is an active problem? *One* occurrence hardly warrants the effort involved in this. How many people are out there even suggesting edits which remove links that aren't actually dead?

Comment: @animuson Your evidence is the screenshot. I wouldn't bother taking the time to post a question to MSO if this was an isolated incident. This is the 2nd or 3rd time I've seen it.

Comment: IMO it should have been flagged as a link-only answer

Comment: @animuson Also, it sounds as if you're basically advocating the fact that people don't even bother to click the URL. A new review audit is necessary.

Comment: In some ways, 3 people accepted the edit. The final reviewer edited the post and rejected the proposed edit, but his edit was essentially to replace the link with a link to archive.org—and acknowledge that the link was dead in his edit summary. I'm not sure an audit is the right way to go, but either this is slightly worrying or the link is dead for some group of people somehow.

Comment: I'm not advocating anything. I'm just pointing out that it's not worth the effort of designing review audits if it rarely ever happens. The whole idea of review audits is to catch robo-reviewers. Would this audit actually help achieve that goal?

Comment: @animuson IMO, somebody who doesn't click a URL when the comment says "dead URL" *is* a robo-reviewer.

Comment: @waiwai933 I've just rolled that back.

Comment: @waiwai933: That's a very valid point. It could very well be inaccessible for those people, which would make the review audit completely invalid.

Comment: For me the link redirects to a 'Canadian Drug Store' if I click on it - oddly only in the answer, not in the suggested edit log.  If I click and open in a new tab the redirect doesn't happen.  Perhaps this is why the suggested edit was made, and one or more reviewers saw the same.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the blog in question was hacked. Even if you're able to get to the blog page through the other link, click on any menu links on the right side of the blog labeled: CODE, REVIEWS, SYSTEMS, TECHNOLOGY, WORDPRESS, or LOG IN, and you'll land on the same very suspicious-looking Canadian drug store web page.

Comment: @martinclayton It seems like that's exactly what's happening. The URL works from the suggested edit log, but not directly from the answer. I've undone the rollback.